# Terminology: All Permutations of Tuple values?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

I want to describe, mathematically, the set of all permutations of values in an n-tuple.

In particular, let $x = p_1 p_2 ... p_n$ where $p_i \in \mathbb{P}^+$ and $p_i \neq p_j \iff i \neq j$. Let $f_x(d) = ( d \mod{p_1}, d \mod{p_2}, \cdots, d \mod{p_n})$ so that $f_x(d)$ is an n-tuple for all $d \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to describe the co-domain of $f_x$, which would be all possible combinations of values for each term of the tuple. Since a tuple is ordered I think permutation is the correct term here to describe the co-domain.

So, for instance, if $x = 6 = 2 * 3$ then $f_x(d) = (d \mod{2}, d \mod{3})$ and the co-domain is the set: $\{ (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2) \}$.

What would be the best terminology to use to describe the co-domain here? The definitions I'm finding online are concerned with bijections of a set to itself rather than with tuples.

Comment: The term you are looking for might be "Cartesian Product".

Comment: @Tzimmo hmmm - yes that might do it :) Thank you

Comment: I assume the $p_i$ are distinct primes?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes; they are distinct primes